# Accessing Python dictionary by field value in QgsExpression

Tags: pyqgis, expression, dictionary

I'm writing a QGIS processing plugin. In this plugin, I use the processing algorithm [`pointsalonglines`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html?highlight=pointsalonglines#points-along-lines), and for the distance parameter, I'd like to use an expression which gives back the value of a dictionary with the key equal to a field value. Not sure that is clear but basically:

```py
mydic = {"id1" : 1, "id2" : 2}
```

and the parameters for `pointsalonglines` algorithm, something like this :

```py
param2 = {'INPUT':layer,
          'DISTANCE': QgsProperty.fromExpression(mydic["idfield"]),
          'START_OFFSET':0,
          'END_OFFSET':0,
          'OUTPUT':'test'}
```

where `idfield` is the name of an existing field in my layer, with values = `"id1"`, `"id2"`, ...

I tried many ways to write my expression but without any success.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Have you tried something like : `QgsProperty.fromExpression("map_get(map('id1', 1, 'id2', 2), \"idfield\")")` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! I first created the list of keys and values from my dictionary : `mymap = []`
 `for k, v in mydic.items():`
    `mymap.extend([k, v])`
    `mymap = tuple(mymap)`
then I used :
`QgsProperty.fromExpression("map_get(map{}, {})".format(str(mymap), \"idfield\"))`

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for the amazing QGIS tutorial.

Comment: That's great if it's useful, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need for that to place as string in `QgsProperty.fromExpression(...)` a QGIS expression, so, you can have the same behavior with a `map` (not a GIS one this time) :

```py
from functools import reduce

mydict = {"id1" : 1, "id2" : 2}
qgis_expr = f'map_get(map{reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, mydict.items())}, "idfield")'
param2 = {
  'INPUT':layer,
  'DISTANCE': QgsProperty.fromExpression(qgis_expr),
  'START_OFFSET':0,
  'END_OFFSET':0,
  'OUTPUT':'test'
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks !! It works ! I had to remove the quotes around the field name though : `qgis_expr = f'map_get(map{reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, mydict.items())}, idfield)'` or if my field name is a variable : `fieldname = "idfield"` `qgis_expr = f'map_get(map{reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, mydict.items())}, {fieldname})'`